# Inserting multiple checked value into one database field with php with dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I'm currently working on a project which requires the user ticking two or more subject checkboxes and then submit to the database but with my current script i'm finding difficulties, it only insert the first checked box with Y, but what i want to achieve is when the user ticks eg. Science and Mathematics, it should be inserted in the database field as `Science,Mathematics`.

```
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "main_form")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO regis (email, write_exam) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString(isset($_POST['written_tests']) ? "true" : "", "defined","'Y'","'N'"));

  mysql_select_db($database_sample, $sample);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $sample) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="subject_form" action="user.php">
<input name="subject" type="checkbox" id="subject" value="Science" />
        Science &nbsp;
        <input name="subject" type="checkbox" id="subject" value="Mathematics" />
        Mathematics&nbsp;
</form>
```

Comment: can you please show the checkbox html code?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

- You should change form check boxes with name subject to array subject[] containing both 'Science' and 'Mathematics' values. Then change SQL inserg code to store subject[] array elements which are checked, and make

  `$selectedSubjects = implode(',', $_POST['subject']);`

and insert $selectedSubjects value into DB.

- Consider changing your HTML to:

`<form id="subject_form" action="user.php">
    <input name="subject[]" type="checkbox" id="subject" value="Science" />
    Science &nbsp;
    <input name="subject[]" type="checkbox" id="subject" value="Mathematics" />
    Mathematics&nbsp;
    </form>`

Comment: how can i do that? i'm new to php and i'm wondering if you can phrase it into my script

Comment: please post HTML form you are using. I'll show you example